# Set up the integral for the volume found by rotating the region bounded by the curves $x=y+1$ and $x=-y^2+2y+3$ about the line $x=-1$

Tags: calculus

Set up the integral for the volume found by rotating the region bounded by the curves $x=y+1$ and $x=-y^2+2y+3$ about the line $x=-1$.
[image: The graph]Thanks! I don't know how to solve it about the line x=-1. I could do it around the x or y axis but the x=-1 confuses me and I don't know how to set it up

Comment: If you shift everything to the right 1 unit, by replacing x by x-1, then you will be rotating around the y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like it is easier to do the integral with respect to $y.$ that is we use the washer method. the range of $y$ is from $-1$ to $2$ the inner radius is $1 + x_l = 1 + y + 1= 2 + y.$   the outer radius is $1 + x_r = 1 -y^2 + 2y + 3 = 4 + 2y - y^2.$  putting all this together, we have $$V = \pi\int_{-1}^2 \left((4+2y-y^2)^2-(2+y)^2 \right)\, dy$$

Answer (score 0):

integrate the area (which I am assuming you can find to be (-y^2 + 2y + 3) - (y+1)) from the lower bound (first intersection of y+1 and the longer equation) to the upper bound (second intersection of the two equations) and I would use the washer method so pi(area+1)^2 - pi((y+1)+1)^2 the reason why we add one to the area is because if you can imagine the object to be rotating around x=-1 you can see that there is 'extra' volume formed by the revolution that would otherwise not be present if it was at x=0.

Comment: sorry i'm new did not know there is a policy concerning self-study questions should i remove my answer

Comment: No you're good thank you!

Comment: i edited the question forgot the subtraction of the smaller area which is pi((y+1)+1)^2

Comment: @Obliv You can fully answer a self-study question. We only expect that the questioner shares his/her own thoughts about the problem.